# WPF Window HorizontalAlignent Stretch

Tags: wpf, window, stretch

I have a simple task that I want to accomplish: Have a WPF window launch with a Horizontal Alignment that is stretched to the total width of the current screen. I want to achieve a kind of custom Overlay MessageBox (I dont want to use third party controls such as MahApps), I am not using any third party references for this.

Please see what I have achieved so far (Not sure if the image will show, the link is https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnQL6.jpg):

[image]

I have tried setting the width with a Controller object that I wrote which works, that basically sets the Width, Height, Left and Top to the width of the primary monitor. Downside is the window then pops up on the primary screen, not on the screen that is currently in use.

Comment: When I set WindowState="Maximized" it does exactly this, but then it moves the window to the top of the screen, and ignores the VerticalAllignment="Center"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I have done the following:

```
var screen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromRectangle(new System.Drawing.Rectangle((int)window.Left, (int)window.Top, (int)window.Width, (int)window.Height));
            window.Width = screen.WorkingArea.Width;
            window.Left = screen.WorkingArea.Left;
```

where window is the instance of my window I want to resize.

This works with the current screen the window was opened on.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, WPF doesn't have any multi-screen functions. You could PInvoke some native [Multiple Display Monitor Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145072(VS.85).aspx), wrap them in a managed class and utilize them in that regard, though.

Comment: Hmm.. I have used this method previously in a screenshot method, but I cant think that something as simple as this should have to be done by invoking native methods?